# How to jump to the first character of the first line of the next/previous block of text?

Tags: cursor-movement, jump

I am aware of `{`and `}` to navigate between blocks of texts , however these jump to blank lines in between blocks of text.

When there are several blank lines in between 2 blocks of text  these do not work symmetrically either.

How can I jump to the first character of the first line of the next/previous block of text , for example the 'B's in the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a search and include `\n`s to match end of lines. Two of them in a row would match a blank line. You can then use `\s*\S` to find the first non-blank character of a line (and ensure you're matching a line with a non-blank character) and use `\zs` to control the start of the match (match that first non-blank character only and none of the spaces.)

```
/\n\n\s*\zs\S
```

You might want to include a special case to match the first non-blank character of the buffer, which you can do with:

```
/\n\n\s*\zs\S\|\%^\_s*\zs\S
```